# <ng-select>:Programmatically updated searchTerm using ViewChild/Children refrence, searchTerm getting replace or not display

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-ngselect

I have requirement to provide input to ng-select dropdown using virtual keyboard and i want to achieve same like working with system keyboard.

for example

-on first key virtual keyboard input programmatically open dropdown.
-show the search term
-option should show according to search input
-on select option search term should get remove and set the form control with updated value on tab change.

so i m trying but not getting why some case search term accepting but some case not.

here is the issue i m facing related to searchTerm on dropdown

-input **replacing** [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-formcontrol-example-searchterm-replacing?file=app/app.component.ts)

-**searchTerm** not showing  [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-querylist-stored-item-update-searchterm-not-showing?file=app/app.component.ts)

-using ng-select refrence by viewChildren QueryList search Term updated but automatically get assigning null(trying but not able to reproduce for providing example)

Any help is very appriciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You are openning but and just enter searchterm  but not firing the search so whatever u pres it just only open and get default 5 values.

Comment: but don't know why #ngselectRef this.ngSelectComp.open() or this.ngSelectComp.isOpen=true not working